# Find adjacency matrix given a list of class labels

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have a list `L` of the items that bellong to the same class, L = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1]
and I want to construct the adjacency matrix 'A' using the list `L` and not 
using any for loop,

```
A = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 1 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 1 1; ]
```

Clould you please help in that?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct result? I would think that the top-right and bottom-left blocks should also contain 1s.

Comment: How do you define that matrix? Why is not `A(6,1)` (for example) equal to `1`?

Comment: Is only the simple case with one class required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
A = zeros(numel(L));
A(logical(L),logical(L)) = 1;
```

The result in your example is

```
A =
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
```

More generally: suppose that you have `L = [1 1 1 0 0 2 2]`, where each number indicates a different class, and zeros don't count. In this case

```
A = bsxfun(@eq,L,L.');
A(~L,~L) = 0;
```

which gives

```
A =
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
```